# Proper way to update package and all dependencies that were previously installed from conda official with conda-forge versions?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3, conda-forge

I have installed `dash` from official conda package management system. That version is severely outdated (from 2019 year). Now I need to update that installed dash and its all dependencies with version from conda-forge (which is latest dash version https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dash). What is the proper way of doing that?

Comment: Does `conda install -c conda-forge dash` work?

Comment: @darthbith I have not tried anything because I do not want to break environment. Is it right way to use `conda install -c conda-forge` for package that is already installed with `conda install`?

Comment: `conda install conda-forge::dash` or `conda install "dash>=x.y"` should work. There should not be any problems with breakage as the conda-solver will replace all packages that are incompatible automatically. In the unlikely case that things do break, you can use `conda install --revision <rev-id>` to undo the change.